# Windows10 log in difficulty

Tags: windows

I reset my windows 10 laptop . I am trying to log in now with my old username n password but it doesn’t work

I have try to reset it again but now it say “this laptop has no administration account , log in first n than try it again”

But how can I log in when my username n password is not working.

I am not able to log in by either local account nor Microsoft account.  I am certain that I remember my password and log in I’d.

I am not able to run any command like windows +R .

My laptop can’t detect USB too.

So how would I log my laptop now.

Please do suggest .

Comment: We need to know which users exist on the machine, enable the built-in Administrator account, which will allow you to login into your computer

Comment: Resetting in Windows 10 usually means "no user" after it's done and you're supposed to create a new local account (or use a Microsoft account). What -- if anything -- isn't working? If you reset it but with the option to keep your user files then those are preserved and so is your account with the exact same pw. Again, please [edit] to provide more info because what you posted so far makes no sense at all.

Comment: I reset my windows 10 laptop. Now I cannot log in. I tried with my old Id n password. I created new ID n password too. But I can’t . Every time it ask for “admin log in “ . My laptop was never having any admin log in . I tried to log in with my freinds ID n password too. But can’t .

Comment: Your friends "ID" does not exist on your WIndows 10 installation.  You would have had to create a user, linked that local user to your friend's ID, for that to even work.  I suggest you enable the built-in Administrator account in order to properly diagnose this problem.

Comment: How to do that ? Can you pls guide ...

Comment: @Nimeshvarlekar - See my answer to the duplicate question

Answer (score -1):

Probably you should use Linux tool, like ntpwchange to break into your system and repair it ( for example unlocking administrator account and resetting password to empty value).

Comment: It is exactly the same answer as in duplicate question. But the difference is, here's downwoted whilst duplicate is accepted. :)